# Factoring as Periodicity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

I try to understand the equivalence between *the problem of factoring a number* and *the problem of finding the period of a number*. I know that there are two lemmas that assure this equivalence, namely

**Lema 1**
Factoring is equivalent with finding a non-trivial square-root of $1$  mod  $N$.

**Lema 2**
Suppose that $N = pq$ and $x \in Z_N$ with $x \neq p$ and $x \neq q$. Then, with probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ we have that the order $s$ of $x$ is even and $x^{s/2}$ is a non-trivial square-root of $1$ mod $N$.

For the first Lemma the proof was very easy, but I can't figure out how to demonstrate the second one. I know that I should apply *Fermat's Little Theorem* and *Chinese Remainder Theorem*. Can you give me some hints please?

Comment: In **Lemma 2**: Did you mean $p,q\not\mid x$ rather than $x\ne p, x\ne q$? Also, what are $p,q$ (presume two different primes!)? Do you assume that neither of them is $2$? (Say, $p=2, q=3$ and $x$ can only be $1$ or $5$, which are both trivial square roots.)